# If...Else, Else block isn't executing when the if condition isn't satisfied

Tags: javascript, if-statement, sessionstorage

I'm struggling to figure out why my else block isn't executing although the if block will execute if the condition is satisfied i'm relatively new to java-script but i have programming experience and i am slightly baffled as to why it wont.

This is the function that is called on $(document).ready:

```
function selectSchool()
    {
        alert("Selecting a School!" + sessionStorage.sCData);
        if (!sessionStorage.sCData || sessionStorage === NULL)
        {
            alert("Its Empty!");
        } else {
            alert("Its Not Empty!");
            //$('#schoolDropdown').val(sessionStorage.sCData);
            //sessionStorage = NULL;
            alert('Session Storage: ' + sessionStorage.sCData);
        }
        alert("Function finished");

    };
```

i am struggling to see any bad syntax but im not too great with javascript with the amount of experience i have with it, i commented out the two lines just too see if it was anything thats happening in them lines that were causing it to not execute adding alerts() to see where the function is able to get to.

Thanks in advance for any help you can give.

Comment: what are you getting in first alert?

Comment: *my else block isn't executing although the if block will execute if the condition is satisfied* -- It is normal. `Else` block wont execute if the `if` condition is true

Comment: change `NULL` to `null`. Also, sessionStorage will never be null.

Comment: Just swap compassion in if statemnt  if (sessionStorage === NULL || !sessionStorage.sCData  )

Comment: The first alert prints out either undefined or has what im looking for depending on what i was testing for, it will be undefined when it gets into the if block but has a school in the else block but when theres a school the else block is completely ignored @Deep

Comment: @Weedozewhen the condition is false the else block is completely ignored

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would switch the condition and check for truthyness of `sessionStorage` and if `sCData` is truthy as well.

```
function selectSchool() {
    alert("Selecting a School!" + sessionStorage.sCData);
    if (sessionStorage && sessionStorage.sCData) {
        alert("Its Not Empty!");
        alert('Session Storage: ' + sessionStorage.sCData);
    } else {
        alert("Its Empty!");
    }
    alert("Function finished");
};
```

Comment: This is the best solution so far. But it also has the problem of throwing a `Uncaught Reference Error: sessionStorage is not defined` in case of sessionStorage being unavailable: `alert("Selecting a School!" + sessionStorage.sCData);`

Comment: Thanks for the reply ill give it a try and let you know how it goes

Comment: for compatibility have a look here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage#Browser_compatibility

Comment: Ive just tried this and it worked perfectly, thankyou for all your help your answer has been marked as correct

Answer (score 2):

First of all, there's no something like NULL in JavaScript. JavaScript is case-sensitive.

Secondly, session storage will never be `null`, so the `sessionStorage == null` condition will always return false.

Finally, the working snippet:

```js
function selectSchool() {
  
  alert("Selecting a School!" + sessionStorage.sCData);
  if (!sessionStorage.sCData) {
    alert("Its Empty!");
  } else {
    alert("Its Not Empty!");
    //$('#schoolDropdown').val(sessionStorage.sCData);
    //sessionStorage = NULL;
    alert('Session Storage: ' + sessionStorage.sCData);
  }
  alert("Function finished");
  
};
```

Comment: This is not the best approach concerning the possible non-availability of `sessionStorage` since in that case it will throw a `Uncaught Reference Error: sessionStorage is not defined`.

Comment: @connexo Give me an example, when session storage will be undefined.

Comment: In old browsers that never implemented it.

Comment: Thanks for your input

Comment: ill give all the suggestions a try

Answer (score 1):

`NULL != null` so replace `NULL` with `null`. Better to use not operator i.e. `!`. It checks if a string is `empty, null or undefined`. Also use like

`if (!sessionStorage.sCData || sessionStorage === null)`

**or**

`if (!sessionStorage.sCData || !sessionStorage)`

example:

```js
(function selectSchool()
    {
      var some="";
        if (!some)
        {
            alert("Its Empty!");
        } else {
            alert("Its Not Empty!");
           

        }
        alert("Function finished");

    })()
```